# Is it good to store URL object in redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-state

I tried to store the URL object in the react store and it is giving me error that:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path:
```

Here is the URL reference in my store.
**Code Reference:**
[image]

**Console error:**
[image]

Is there an alternative way to store URL or how can we fix this error?

Comment: Store it as a string?

Comment: It is in a interface. Storing it as string will be difficult here as we need to maintain one more similar interface (with just 1 field changed) to have a string datatype inplace of URL and again and again we have to convert it when we need it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have in the error, you should store only serializable data in the Redux store.

Get only the href propery like that:

```js
const yourUrl = new URL(...);
console.log(yourUrl.href);
```

More documentation here on the MDN Website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: It is in interface. Storing it as string will be difficult here as we need to maintain one more similar interface (with just 1 field changed) to have a string datatype inplace of URL and again and again we have to convert it when we need it.